# yahoo json.engine Is this file bad, malware or anything like that? Do you have it in your browser?

Tags: json, security, yahoo, mcafee

Im very sorry if Im wrong by posting this question here. Since you are programmers I think you are the best people to ask to, anyway. 
While I was developing a web application and checking some things in the console I detected a file json.engine

[image]

[image: Another ss]
If you have mcafee do you have it too?. It appears not only in the apps I develop but also when I use other web pages such as stackoverflow, facebook, google etc.

I found out that the id it has comes from Mcafee extension but I don't think yahoo is linked to Mcafee, so Can you see any malicious thing in the screen shot?

Thanks for your time, If there is a better place where I cold ask this question I'd appreciate if you could tell me where.

As far as I know this json is not doing somethig bad but I know that It could be sending data to some place for I don't know what purposes.

As you can see, this file appears in google as shown in the next screen shot:
[image]

It comes form an extension:
[image]

I found out that its a Mcafee extension but is it good?
[image]

Comment: You've hidden (or left out) all of the information we could possibly use to determine where that file is coming from, so we have absolutely no way of knowing whether it's normal or not.

Comment: They are just resoures from my website, Ill add more details and information, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are search engines. Nothing more.

Comment: Good that's what I needed to know, If you cold tell me what are their purpose it would be great.

Comment: The engines.json file just contains your current setup for search engines (preferred, URL, update settings). McAfee WebAdvisor does a lookup of search results, to protect you against malicious websites (see _Search securely_: https://www.siteadvisor.com/final/index.html). You may -or may not- get rid of the extension. If you ask me, it forms a larger danger in terms of privacy than security-